# get_post() with a specific class only - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Wordpress as the CMS for a site the I'm building.

the page template:

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>

    <!-- Class here -->

    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="content" class="column">
            <?php if( have_posts() ): while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

            <div class="post">

            <?php the_content(); ?>

            </div>

            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        </div>

        <div id="sidebar" class="column">
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</div>
&nbsp;
<div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I need a div with the class of "`theslide`" to be called before the `#wrap (Class here)` and not to be call again by the php that follows.

Can one do something along the lines of "`get_post if class=theslide`" ?

Thank you.

Comment: the question seem confusing, do you mind if you explain it further? when do you want the class to show? which pages will be using this class/template? is this code you posted in the index.php or in the page.php? there are a lot of things to keep in mind. you could learn a lot more here in the [wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) about theme development.

Comment: This will be for both 'index.php' and 'page.php', the class must show before the div starts, '<!-- Class here -->', this is because the div has a set width and the content of the class needs to be wider than this.

The class will be present on each page, this is to call in a short code for a image slider, but each page will have a unique slider while using the same template.

Comment: pls tell me if im correct, you only need the <div> wrapper when the slider is present? or it will be present on all the pages but the slider changes?

Comment: All pages will have the slider and the wrap <div>. Normal body content needs to be called inside the <div>, but the slider needs to be called before the <div>. Each page will have a unique slider.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the input, a friend of mine helped me out.

If anyone else has the same problem:

```
<?php if( have_posts() ): while( have_posts() ): the_post();

$post_content = get_the_content();
preg_match('/(<div.*?class="theslide".*?<\/div>)(.*)/ism', $post_content, $content);

if( isset($content[1]) )
{
    echo $content[1];            //print the "theslide" div
    $page_content = $content[2];
}
else
{
    $page_content = $post_content;

}
?>

<div id="wrap">
    <div id="content" class="column">

        <div class="post">
            <?php echo $page_content; ?>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="sidebar" class="column">
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin to add custom fields to your post
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

and then in your loop, you can add a condition like

```
<?php 
     if(get_field('your_field_name' )){
        //add class 
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem ideal for something that needs to be implemented across 70+ pages, especially since the number of pages are set to increase.

Comment: Is there no way to have something like

`<?php
if (class_exists('theslide')) {
}
?>`

And then eco that?

Comment: you cant add a condition to check if the class exists in the php file.. you will have to set a parameter to the post and then check if the post has that particular parameter or not.

Comment: The class doesn't exist in the php file, it exists in the Wordpress page, the php file must read this and display it prior to displaying the rest of the page content.